# SVG not showing in browsers on iOS (iphone, ipad)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, svg

On my site there is a block with a map that is made as a SVG sprite, if you hover over a point, the whole map becomes darker and only the selected object remains. Everything works fine on the desktop and android, but on IOS in Safari and Chrome it doesn't want to work it out (the map turns white).
Site link: http://lorri.beget.tech

[Map example(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PDX8.jpg)

Comment: Your `index.html` is ~14MB and took almost 20s to fully load **on a desktop computer**. 26s until the entire page is done loading. 3 background images of ~3, 3 and 7MB. And about that SVG, it's plastered with inline images. Did you check how big this thing is? No wonder that a smartphone would deny the memory for that.

Comment: SVG has about 19MB, but why its work fine on android and not showing on IOS. What is the solving of this?